# Manual Shutdown, Won't Restart on Demand

Tags: shutdown, restart

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS single boot - however I'm sure it's not Ubuntu's fault.

It's the weirdest thing and why I don't shutdown often, but had to in order to replace a hard drive. It won't restart until several hours later, if left alone.
Anyone else experience anything similar?
This thing has a 1000 watt PSU and relatively new motherboard.

Comment: If you'd like help with this, you should provide specifics.  Tell us exactly what you're doing to reproduce the issue and exactly what happens.  Reproduce any errors here verbatim and unredacted being sure to retain formatting and line breaks.

Comment: All I'm doing is shutting down the workstation — It won't startup immediately. I had to leave it for about 8 hours and then it restarted normally. I'm suspecting the power supply — I mean what else could it be? There aren't any errors or messages to provide because the computer doesn't get powered on, therefore no POST messages. It's a damn good power supply too.

Comment: Do you mean the device is OFF and when you use the power button it does absolutely nothing? No fans, no lights, no noises?  That sure does sound like a PSU issue. It doesn't matter how expensive or capacious the PSU - that doesn't affect failure rates. And a 1000W PSU is grossly inappropriate for most computers.  Do you have 2 CPUs and 4 GPUs or something? What is the state of the other hardware in the system and are you sure everything is connected properly?  Turning on/off is a basic function of any electronic device that you shouldn't be afraid of...

Comment: If it's not Ubuntus fault, then it's your hardware and I suggest you sort it out because power issues can fry your parts.  I'm not sure how we would be able to help if the problem isn't related to the OS.

Comment: Yup when off (Cold restart). Strangest thing, I have to wait for an hour or so and refrain from touching the power button in the meantime or the time starts over again. Damn I'll have to see if warranty still covers it.
Thanks. Just wanted another head .... uno 2 heads are ...